# slurm get job id within bash

Tags: python, bash, batch-processing, slurm

Is there a built in way to get the ID of a slurm job when it is being run?

I can imagine determining the ID by parsing squeue and matching the ID to the hostname (e.g. `socket.gethostname()` in python). Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The job ID is assigned to the `SLURM_JOB_ID` environment variable. So in Python, you would get it with

```
import os
print(os.environ["SLURM_JOB_ID"])
```

Note that even though the job id is an integer, the environment variable contains a character string so you will need to call the `int()` function to convert it.